# Upgrade angular 5 to angular 11

Tags: angular, angular5, upgrade, angular11

I have an app that is running on angular 5.2. It uses Angular Material and PrimeNG as well. I went to https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=5.2-11.0 and it shows all the updates that need to be done, but there is a warning that they do not recommend moving across multiple major versions. So, my questions is, do I need to make 6 hops to get to angular 11 or is there alternate shorter route anyone can recommend to get to the angular 11? Did any one upgraded theirs by moving across multiple major versions without any issues?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know it will be helpful or not but I have updated a project of primeNG application from Angular 6 to 11. Please try this process if you want to =>

=> Prerequisite 
1. Install Node.js Latest

2.Install TypeScript For Visual Studio Latest(FOR Windows Visual Studio)

3. For Linux or MAC USE `npm uninstall -g typescript@latest`
then `npm install -g typescript@latest`

**Step 1:** 
1.`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

2.`npm cache clean --force`

3.`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

**Step 2:**

1.`npm i -g npm-check-updates`

2.`ncu -u`

3.`npm install --save`
**Note:** You can also check that site. It was helpful for me. LINK=> [Update-Angular](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-update-local-angular-cli-version/#.X0R7sMgzbI)

Comment: Thanks! Will check the site and proceed.